# face book like button not updates the like count after login

Tags: iframe, facebook-like, mobile-application

I am using iframe facebook like button on my app(mobile). When I hit the like button without 
login -> login window opens-> after login -> the login window hides. But the like count is not updated until refresh and hit the like button again. Please help and thanks in advance.

Note: i want a solution for iframe facebook like button only. Thanks